# Load data to DataGrid when there are just 5 rows to see

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bound to `EmployeeDataTable` property. Let’s consider that count of rows of `EmployeeDataTable` is 50 . That is,  `DataGrid` has 50 rows.

```
private DataTable employeeDataTable;
public DataTable EmployeeDataTable
{
   get { return employeeDataTable; }
   set {
            employeeDataTable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeDataTable");
       }
}
```

What I want is when user scrolls to the bottom or to the top of the `DataGrid`(50 rows) and there are just 5 rows to see(at the top or at the top), then I would like to add the next 20 items to the `DataGrid`(to the top of Datagrid if user scrolls to Topor to the bottom if user scrolls to the bottom).

That is, I would like to run a method called `GetNewData()`, when user sees the forty fifth (45) row or the fifth(5) of `DataGrid`. Is it possible to do without `SelectedItem` property?(Just by using `Scroll`)

```
private void GetNewData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)//Adding 20 DataRows
    {
       var theRow = employeeDataTable.NewRow();
       for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
       {             
          theRow[j] = "o";
       }                
       Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
       {
           employeeDataTable.Rows.Add(theRow); 
       }));
   }
}
```

It looks like when user scrolls down or scroll up in `DataGrid` and my method `GetNewData()` loads new data in background thread. It is like paging but without buttons “Next” and “Previous” (I cannot use the buttons).

[image]

I’ve tried to handle many events such as `MouseWheel` or `MouseMove` of `DataGrid` but there is no result. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for "DataGrid virtualization WPF" in google. One lovely article : http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/498#.VmMTC-affws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is wrap your data grid in a `ScrollableView` and register to the `ScrollChanged` event:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              PreviewMouseWheel="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseWheel"
              ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_OnScrollChanged">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"></DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Next, you implement the `ScrollChanged` event to check if you are at the bottom of the `ScrollView` and if so then add some rows.

```
private void ScrollViewer_OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var sv = sender as ScrollViewer;

    if (sv != null && !_addingData)
    {
        if (sv.ScrollableHeight - e.VerticalOffset == 0)
        {
            _addingData = true;
            GetNewData();
            _addingData = false;
         }
     }
} 

    private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer scv = (ScrollViewer)sender;
        scv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scv.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

You don't need to add any observable stuff to your `EmployeeDataTable` if you register the datagrid like this:

```
dg.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dg.ItemsSource = EmployeeDataTable.DefaultView;
```

EDIT: Updated to enable mouse wheel scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for asking this.  It motivated me to write an article about it.  http://thesharp.ninja/dynamically-adding-data-to-xaml-datagrid-on-demand/

Comment: OK, it was simple enough to add support for mouse wheel scrolling.  See the edits.

Comment: It really works, but I cannot figured out how to implement calling GetNewData() method when there is 5 rows in DataGrid, but not when scroll meets the bounds of DataGrid.